# Not able to Start Intent in TextView (programmatically created) inside the getView method of Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent

The compiler shows "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new `View.OnClickListener(){}`"

```
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dharmesh = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fact , parent, false);

    topLayout = (LinearLayout) dharmesh.findViewById(R.id.layoutone);
    TextView tv;

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) dharmesh.findViewById(R.id.image);

    if(list.get(position).getType().equals("Water"))
    {

    }


    else if(list.get(position).getType().equals("Computer"))
    {
        int size = list.get(position).getArrayString().size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {

            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.toilet);
            tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 0 ,1f));
            tv.setText(list.get(position).getArrayString().get(i));
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            tv.setEnabled(true);
            tv.setClickable(true);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent it = new Intent(context , SchoolListShow.class);
                    // i.putExtra("School", list.get(0).getSchoolList());
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

            topLayout.addView(tv);
        }
    }
    return dharmesh;
}
```

What is the issue friends

Comment: it is a compile time error ... seems like you don't know java at all ... read the error again it just saying that startActivity is not a method from View.OnClickListener class/interface ... startActivty is a method of Context class ...

Comment: That can be true Selvin but this will not help the OP very much. We expect you to give a working solution also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code....

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent it = new Intent(context , SchoolListShow.class);
                    // i.putExtra("School", list.get(0).getSchoolList());
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });
```

To...

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent it = new Intent(context , SchoolListShow.class);
                    // i.putExtra("School", list.get(0).getSchoolList());

                    // startActivity is a member of the context, not of the OnClickListener.
                    context.startActivity(it);
                }
            });
```

The startActivity() method does not exist on the OnClickListener type it lives on the context or activity.

Comment: Thanks Man .. A rookie mistake